# A few questions about windows 7 snapshots

Tags: windows-7, backup, raid, snapshot, vss

I have been googling a while, but I am a bit confused about Microsoft VSS technology.

Currently I am running Windows 7 Enterprise 64bit - everything patched to the latest versions. My system has one soft-RAID5 LUN configured which I would like to backup to my USB disk.

Now I am wondering if snapshots are the right way to backup my drive. If yes, how can I create a snapshot of my raid 5 drive and transfer the snapshot to my USB disk? Will I be able to do a single-file restore?

Thanks in advance
Matthias

Comment: Which method are you going to use `Full Copy/Split Mirror` or `Differential Copy`?

Comment: I have no idea how this methods can be used or even configured. Is that related to vssadmin.exe?

Comment: I copied and pasted those two terms from the documentation on the feature itself.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for ["Previous Versions" information](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows7/previous-versions-of-files-frequently-asked-questions), which uses VSS to snapshot the partition(s).